# I want to hide Columns on each sheet according to a value in Cells in row 1

Tags: javascript

I get an error every time I try this here is what I am using. I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot find function hideColumns in object Sheet,Sheet,Sheet,Sheet,Sheet."
```

I am not very familiar with scripts and cant seem to get this to work.

```
function Hide() {
  // get active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    // look at all sheets
  var sheet = ss.getSheets();

  // get data
  var data = ss.getDataRange();

  // get number of columns
  var lastCol = data.getLastColumn()+1;

  Logger.log(lastCol);

  // itterate through columns
  for(var i=1; i<lastCol; i++) {
     if(data.getCell(1, i).getValue()[0] == '*') {
        sheet.hideColumns(i);
     }
  }
}
```

Could some one help me?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, you are using [this reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet). I guess, you want to do the following:

1. Iterate all the columns in the data range.
2. If the value of the first row of column equals `*` then hide that column.

I am not familiar with Google Apps Services, but I think your code should look like this:

```
function Hide() {
  // get active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    // look at all sheets
  //var sheet = ss.getSheets();

  // get data
  var data = ss.getDataRange();

  //get the sheet this range belongs to.
  var sheet = data.getSheet();

  // get number of columns
  var lastCol = data.getLastColumn()+1;

  Logger.log(lastCol);

  // itterate through columns
  for(var i=1; i<lastCol; i++) {
     if(data.getCell(1, i).getValue()[0] == '*') {
        sheet.hideColumns(i);
     }
  }
}
```

Since `.getSheets` return an **Array** of `Sheet` objects you can not call that function.